Can a landlord force me to pay utilities with a money order/cashiers check?
In California. Landlord sent an email saying that they can no longer take checks from my unit and I had to pay via money order/cashier's check. I did bounce a check this month, death in the family and I forgot to transfer funds so this was my fault and I'm okay with paying in an alternative way for the rent however...
The landlord recently took over the shared utilities and instead of paying a company, we have to pay them directly. I've never bounced a check for the utilities and would rather continue to pay those via card. The law specifies rent but not utilties.

A lease will often specify this specifically in its terms. The terms of the lease could matter.

When the landlord took over utilities did you have to sign a separate contract/agreement? Was that based on terms of the original lease? Or did they just tell you they were doing it? Liability for utilities is normally explicitly covered in the lease so they shouldn't just be able to change that.

When the landlord took over utilities did you have to sign a separate contract/agreement?  No. They just sent us a notice that they were taking over the utilities. The notice they recently sent said that they could not take checks from my unit.
